# Redis: how to update master from slave?

Tags: redis, replication

we have two redis servers
we need both to be identical.
if any client update any server, the server must update the other server.

I just tried out redis replication future
it is great, but it's working in one way Master => slave

I need to make it works in two ways

> Master => slave
>
> Master <= slave

if that possible?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is known as a multi-master setup, which is not possible with Redis.